# Is StreamingBody a derived class of urlib3?

Tags: boto3

For objects that gets returned by `client.get_object()`, is it possible to convert to use such object as an IOStream? It is unclear whether or not StreamingBody is a derived class of urlib3 or just has some of that functionality. I want to be able to return the object as an IOStream of sort.

Answer (score 0):

No, [`StreamingBody`](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/response.py#L29) is a wrapper, not a subclass.